# Find match in any key excluding X

Tags: elasticsearch

I have index with following structure:

```
 1. entry_id
 2. workspace_id
 3. <some_dynamic_key_1>
 4. <some_dynamic_key_2>
 ...
 n+2. <some_dynamic_key_n>
```

And I want to find all documents that contain a certain workspace, and any dynamic key matches a certain value (excluding `entry_id` and `workspace_id`).

I found something like this:

```
{
   "query": {
     "bool": {
       "should":[{"match": { "_all": "abc" }],
       "filter": {"term": {"workspace_id": "People"}}
    }
  }
}
```

But firstly, the `_all` key is deprecated in version 6 of elasticsearch, and secondly `_all` does not exclude the `entry_id` and `workspace_id`e keys

Answer (score 0):

This is a good use case for the [`copy_to` mapping parameter](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/copy-to.html).

In your mapping, you simply need to designate all the fields that you want  the value to be copied in an "all" field containing all your dynamic key values, like this:

```
PUT my-index-000001
{
  "mappings": {
    "properties": {
      "entry_id": {
        "type": "keyword"
      },
      "workspace_id": {
        "type": "keyword"
      },
      "some_dynamic_key_1": {
        "type": "text",
        "copy_to": "all_dynamic_keys" 
      },
      "some_dynamic_key_2": {
        "type": "text",
        "copy_to": "all_dynamic_keys" 
      },
      "all_dynamic_keys": {
        "type": "text"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Then you can simply query that new field

```
{
   "query": {
     "bool": {
       "should":[{"match": { "all_dynamic_keys": "abc" }],
       "filter": {"term": {"workspace_id": "People"}}
    }
  }
}
```